# ZBar jar in android

Tags: android

zbar jar in my project for barcode scanning. While loading libiconv.so in system library like

```
 static 
{
    System.loadLibrary("iconv");
}
```

I got the following errors,

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.scanner mobile-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.scanner.mobile-2/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libiconv.so"
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:367)
   at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1076)
```

Note:
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

This project is worked well in eclipse after migration to android studio the above error was thrown.

Comment: The error states that it couldn't find `liblibiconv.so.so`. Are you sure you are not calling `System.loadLibrary("libiconv.so");` instead of `System.loadLibrary("iconv");` somewhere?

Comment: Hi daniel that error shows only couldn't find libiconv.so, I mistakenly wrote that liblibiconv.so.so

Comment: The problem is resolved now,  I kept the library files(libiconv.so) files in libs folder- for eclipse its worked fine, while migrating to android studio we need to keep this library files in jniLibs folder, then only android studio recognize these libraries files.